# How to get variable from pdo query? Error showed

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to get variable from pdo query but I got an error and could not figure it out. Error I get is PDO::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given.

// first I get variable, and when I echo variable I get good result.

```
$id=$_POST("kolicina");

$stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT Kolicina FROM table1 where Kolicina=$id");

$q=$conn->query($stmt);

while($row = $q ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  $kolicina=$row["Kolicina"];
}

echo $kolicina;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use instead:

```
id=$_POST("kolicina");

$stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT Kolicina FROM table1 where Kolicina=:id");

$stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));
```

the :id is binded to $id on the execute statement.

And to fetch the result use:

```
 $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: In addition you should replace the round brackets when getting your data from `$_POST` into square brackets `$id = $_POST['kolicina']`

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to be like this:

```
$stmt=$conn->prepare('SELECT Kolicina FROM table1 where Kolicina = :id');
$array = array('id' => $id);
$stmt->execute($array);
```

And you can fecth all results like this:

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
   print_r($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First read here [PHP MANUAL PDO](http://php.net/pdo)
Second what you did there is wrong.

```
$id = $_POST['yourvarfromform'];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Kolicina = :id");
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR) // if it's string you can check on pdo manual because you can use int and others.
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($result as $key => $value {
    // Run Some Code Here
}
```

Comment: woops my bad i'm paying atention to two computers :D